# Read Emails From Outlook using Python Fails if Meeting Invites Are Present

Tags: python, outlook

I've been able to work out some code through some learning and experiments from resources on the web.

I'm stuck at a point that everytime an there is a meeting invite in my outlook mailbox. The code fails to execute.

Looking for guidance on how to handle the exception in Python.

```
import csv  
import win32com.client

from datetime import datetime

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items

# Create empty list to store results
data_set = list()
date_id = (datetime.today()).strftime('%Y%m%d') # Used to create the filename

#Iterating through email items in outlook folder  

for message in messages:
    if messages is not None:
         if len(inbox.Items) > 0:
                row = list()
                row.append(message.Subject)
                row.append(message.Categories)
                row.append(message.Sender)
                #row.append(message.Sender.Address)
                row.append(message.To)
                row.append(message.SentOn)
                row.append(message.CC)
                row.append(message.BCC)
                 
                # Stores the data in a list
                data_set.append(row)
                    
                
# Print out the result to a csv with headers
with open(date_id + "_"+ 'outlook_Data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    headers = ['Subject', 'Category', 'From', 'To', 'Sent On', 'CC', 'BCC']
    wr = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    wr.writerow(headers)
    for line in data_set:
        wr.writerow(line)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'fails to execute'?  Does it raise an exception?

Comment: It throws an attribution error pointing to the line (message.Sender).                     
raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))

AttributeError: <unknown>.Sender

Comment: Further research shows that emails are considered a different class and meeting invites another. As long as there are no meeting invites in the mailbox the program runs smoothly.

Comment: So `if isinstance(message, TheMeetingInviteClass):continue`?

Comment: Yes, Tried applying the if isinstance(message, TheMeetingInviteClass):continue at the beginning of the for message in messages: but it does not work. Am I applying the code line incorrectly?

Comment: @snakecharmerb did the logic work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem reduces to a filtering problem: we have a list of objects of different types, some of which must not be processed.

For the purposes of this answer, let the email objects in the inbox be of type `Message`, and the meeting invitations be of type `MeetingInvitation`.

Any of these four approaches can be applied.

1. try/except/continue

   ```
   for message in messages:
       row = list()
       try:
           row.append(message.Subject)
           row.append(message.Categories)
           row.append(message.Sender)
           ...                 
           # Stores the data in a list
           data_set.append(row)
       except AttributeError as ex:
           print('Error', ex, 'skipping message', message)
           continue
   ```
2. Check the type of the object at the top of the loop

   ```
    for message in messages:
        if isinstance(message, MeetingInvitation):
            continue
        row = list()
   ```
3. Use the [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) built-in function

   ```
    filtered_messages = filter(lambda msg: not isinstance(msg, MeetingInvitation), messages)
    for message in filtered_messages:
        row = list()
        ...
   ```
4. Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (If there are a *lot* of messages, a generator comprehension would be more efficient - replace `[]` with `()`)

   ```
    filtered_messages = [msg for msg in msgs if not isinstance(msg, MeetingInvitation)] 
    for message in filtered_messages:
        row = list()
        ...
   ```

The isinstance checks could be reversed to exclude *anything* that isn't a `Message`

```
if not isinstance(message, Message):
   continue
```

or extended to exclude other problematic types

```
if isinstance(message, (MeetingInvitation, SomethingElse)):
    continue
```

All of the four approaches are functionally equivalent.  The filter and list comprehension approaches are cleaner, in my opinion, because they separate the filtering process from the actual message processing.

Comment: I tried the try/except/continue method and it worked flawlessly. The perfect solution. I'm still learning python so "AttributeError" handling piece is quite new to me. I could not get the other two methods to work. I'm doing some research on the "isinstance" method i'm sure I'm not applying that correctly for now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the one more solution IF YOU WANT TO SKIP THE OUTLOOK CALADER ITEM , by using `item.MessageClass` below is the sample code and reference link for more details

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/Concepts/Forms/item-types-and-message-classes

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

for i, msg in enumerate(messages):
    print(msg.MessageClass) # use this in condition

    if msg.MessageClass=='IPM.Note':
        print('Its a Meeting')

        # Identify outlook exchange user
        if msg.SenderEmailType == "EX":
            print(msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress)
            msg_sender = msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
        else:
            print(msg.SenderEmailAddress)
            msg_sender = msg.SenderEmailAddress
    elif msg.MessageClass =='IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request':
        print('Its a Meeting')
    # Check only first 20 items change the number as required
    if i > 20:
        break
```

> ```
> Some Outputs from above code
> IPM.Note
> IPM.Note
> IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request
> Its a Meeting
> IPM.Note
> IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request
> Its a Meeting
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to @snakecharmerb for helping through the challenges. The complete working code is below if anyone else might need to work on something similar.

```
import csv  
import win32com.client
from datetime import datetime

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items


# Create empty list to store results
data_set = list()
date_id = (datetime.today()).strftime('%Y%m%d') # Used to create the filename

#Iterating through email items in outlook folder  

for message in messages:
    row = list()
    try:
        row.append(message.Subject)
        row.append(message.Categories)
        row.append(message.Sender)
        row.append(message.Sender.Address)
        row.append(message.To)
        row.append(message.SentOn)
        row.append(message.CC)
        row.append(message.BCC)
                
 
        # Stores the data in a list
        data_set.append(row)
    except AttributeError as ex:
      print('Error', ex, 'skipping message', message)
      continue
                
# Print out the result to a csv with headers
with open(date_id + "_"+ 'outlook_Data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    headers = ['Subject', 'Category', 'From', 'To', 'Sent On', 'CC', 'BCC']
    wr = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    wr.writerow(headers)
    for line in data_set:
        wr.writerow(line)
```