# Issue: Unable to convert Py file to EXE where PyFile is designed to fetch data from Outlook Mail

Tags: python, outlook

I have one Py file that collects Outlook email details for analysis. I was able to get the code completed with some help referenced in this [stackoverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63721937/read-emails-from-outlook-using-python-fails-if-meeting-invites-are-present) Now i'm tasked with sharing the code with other users who might not have python installed but would simply like to use it as an EXE file to get the data and do some basic analysis. I've tried various options including the following, however they all have the same error.

I've also tried this on a machine with Administrator rights.

1. Pyinstaller
2. Auto Py to Exe

Can any one provide some guidance on what might be going wrong.

The error message reads "Failed to execute script filename"

#EDIT based on 09/08/2020

While the exe file generated did not work, the pyc file that was generated worked to provide the output. However this is not transferable to another machine to work as an EXE.

Comment: Your error message is the default error pyInstaller throws in its EXEs when something goes wrong. Does the console window display any errors? They are often more informative. Please post a list of the packages and the package manager you used, too. Most times pyInstaller just fails to bundle the packages correctly.

Comment: csv, win32com.client, datetime, os - I do not see any errors throw up on the console.

Comment: Did you use `--onefile` in pyInstaller?

Comment: --onefile does not work at all. At least with the directory version I'm able to get a pyc file but with --onefile all I get is the error.

Comment: Ok, so do you have a minimum working example? Some dummy code that imports the same packages as your code and produces the same error. Otherwise, it is hard to help.

Comment: The entire code is available in the issue description as a link. you can find it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63721937/read-emails-from-outlook-using-python-fails-if-meeting-invites-are-present this fetches data from your outlook inbox folder and writes to a csv file in the same location where the py file is present.

Comment: I tried to replicate it and received the error message `File "win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 516, in __getattr__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32timezone'
[10680] Failed to execute script test
`. I fixed it by adding `--hidden-import win32timezone
` to teh pyinstaller call.

Comment: Let me give that a try. In the meantime. Can you tell me how you found the error. I ask this because i still do not see an error throwing up if I ask the system to keep the console open while executing the app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221157/discussion-between-tilman151-and-ares-zephyr).